# Image was not shown in LaTeX (with TeXstudio GUI), only a black filled box is shown

Tags: graphics, texstudio

This is the mini example that I used.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,reqno,twoside]{amsart}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}

\begin{document}
\section{A section}
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=0.8,keepaspectratio]{figure1.JPG}
\caption{Write some caption here}\label{figure1}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

The following figure is the display in dvi viewer:

[image]

The following is the actual image in file "figure1.JPG" that LaTeX is supposed to display:

[image]

What is the problem in my LaTeX code?

Comment: Typically, you would omit the extension ".JPG" in the file name. Also, what happens if you move into the directory in which the DVI file and the JPG files reside and then invoke the DVI viewer from there. Does the black box disappear?

Comment: Finally, what happens if you convert the dvi file to a pdf file using "dvipdf". Do you get any error messages?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! First of all, I would remove the `demo` option.

Comment: That's what `[demo]` means,

Comment: @ClaudioFiandrino. Your suggestion worked!  Thanks a lot for the quick help.  Please copy your comment to Answer section so that I can accept it.

Comment: @DCTLib.  Thanks a lot for the suggestions. I forgot to mention that I did it with and without the "JPG" suffix and it did not help. The JPG image and DVI file do reside in the same folder. I double clicked DVI file and Yap still showed blackbox.

Comment: I tried several things. (1) no [demo] option,pedflatex,internal pdf viewer worked fine. (2) [demo] option,pdflatex,internal pdf viewer showed blackbox. (3) no [demo] option, latex,dvi viewer did not compile. error message is:cannot determined the graphic size in figure1.JPG.(4)[demo] option, latex,dvi viewer showed blackbox.

Comment: Std LaTeX does note support JPG files. `[demo]` just replaces any included images with a common black box